# error: expected ‘;’, identifier or ‘(’ before ‘struct’

Tags: c, struct

```
struct proc_time /* info and times about a single process*/ 
{ 
    pid_t pid; /* pid of the process*/ 
    char name[16]; /* file name of the program executed*/ 
    unsigned long start_time; /* start time of the process*/ 
    unsigned long real_time; /* real time of the process execution*/ 
    unsigned long user_time; /* user time of the process*/ 
    unsigned long sys_time; /* system time of the process*/ 
}; 

struct proctimes /* info and times about all processes we need*/ 
{ 
    struct proc_time proc; /* process with given pid or current process */ 
    struct proc_time parent_proc; /* parent process*/ 
    struct proc_time oldest_child_proc; /* oldest child process*/ 
    struct proc_time oldest_sibling_proc; /* oldest sibling process*/ 
};
```

I can't understand what is going wrong with my declarations and I am getting the following error in the line the second `struct` starts:

> expected ‘;’, identifier or ‘(’ before ‘struct’".

Comment: Can you post the code that comes before this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are using /.../ as a comment delimiter which is illegal.  The line:

```
struct proc_time proc; /process with given pid or current process/
```

Should be replaced with:

```
 struct proc_time proc; /* process with given pid or current process */
```

Comment: Yes, it's even visible in the syntax highlighting.

Comment: Or `struct proc_time proc; // process with given pid or current process`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I have it with /* */ in my code.Just forgot it when typing the question.There is no problem with the comments.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real reason this can happen if you declare these structs in *file scope* (assuming you fixed your comment problem).

However, if you somehow managed to declare these structs inside a bigger struct, then you will indeed get an error from a C compiler

```
struct some_struct
{

  struct proc_time
  { 
    ...
  }; /* <- error: identifier expected */

  struct proctimes
  { 
    ...
  }; /* <- error: identifier expected */

};
```

In C language it is illegal to declare struct types in "nested" fashion without immediately declaring a data field of that type.

Answer (score 0):

Adding struct aliases, before the semicolon and after the closing curly bracket,  allowed me to compile your structs (with gcc after adding a main method and including stdlib.h).

```
struct proc_time /* info and times about a single process*/ 
{ 
    pid_t pid; /* pid of the process*/ 
    char name[16]; /* file name of the program executed*/ 
    unsigned long start_time; /* start time of the process*/ 
    unsigned long real_time; /* real time of the process execution*/ 
    unsigned long user_time; /* user time of the process*/ 
    unsigned long sys_time; /* system time of the process*/ 
} proc_time; 

struct proctimes /* info and times about all processes we need*/ 
{ 
    struct proc_time proc; /* process with given pid or current process */ 
    struct proc_time parent_proc; /* parent process*/ 
    struct proc_time oldest_child_proc; /* oldest child process*/ 
    struct proc_time oldest_sibling_proc; /* oldest sibling process*/ 
} proctimes;
```